# Quantmod monthly returns and class of object

Tags: r, quantmod

I am learning R this semester and I am trying to complete an assignment but am having trouble. Here is what the assignment is asking me to do:

i.  Download daily price data of S&P500 and a stock of your choice for the period 01/01/1993 to 12/31/2013

ii. Compute the monthly returns for the S&P 500 and the stock. 
Useful Hints

- You can use the monthlyReturn() function from Quantmod package (use adjusted closing price from the dataframe of the price of the stock)

iii.    Construct summary statistics, histogram, correlation matrix of the return series

Okay, so I thought this was much simple and here is what I have:

```
getSymbols("SPY",from="1993-01-01", to="2013-12-31")
getSymbols("AAPL",from="1993-01-01", to="2013-12-31")

monthlyReturn(SPY)
monthlyReturn(AAPL)
```

My problem is that the class of each stock is 'xts' 'zoo' and therefore when I attempt to construct the statistics, histogram, and correlation, I am receiving errors. I must be misunderstanding Part 2 because its referencing the dataframe. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is exactly the problem? `hist(monthlyReturn(SPY))` returns a histogram, `cor(monthlyReturn(SPY), monthlyReturn(AAPL))` returns a correlation and `summary(monthlyReturn(SPY))` also returns the summary stats.

Comment: I think I am just confused by the Professor's hint in pt.2 to use adjusted closing price from the data frame

Comment: In that case you need to use `spy_returns_adjusted <- monthlyReturn(SPY$SPY.Adjusted)` not `monthlyReturn(SPY)`

Comment: Would this not return the exact same results? I am confused by what the difference here is?

Comment: Not the same. Just look at the means when you do the summary. They will be different as the adjusted prices are slightly different.